Are these equivalence relations for the Permutation group equivalent?
 Definitions 

$\mathcal{C}$ is the $n$-qubit Clifford group.
$\mathcal{P}_C$ is the group of $n$-qubit permutation matrices in the $n$-qubit Clifford group. This group is generated by all CNOTs and Pauli $X$ strings. Note that for all $n$, $\mathcal{P}_C$ is a strict subgroup of $\mathcal{C}$.
$\mathcal{P}$ is the group of all $n$-qubit unitary permutation matrices. There are $2^n!$ such binary unitary matrices. Note that when $n\ge 3$ this group contains many non-Clifford elements. And so for $n \ge 3$, $\mathcal{P}_C$ is a strict subgroup of $\mathcal{P}$

Equivalence relation 1: $P_1 \equiv_1 P_2$ iff $P_1 = Q_L P_2 Q_R$ for some $Q_L,Q_R \in \mathcal{P}_C$. Here $P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$.
Equivalence relation 2: $P_1 \equiv_2 P_2$ iff $P_1 = C_L P_2 C_R$ for some $C_L,C_R \in \mathcal{C}$. Here $P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$.
 Question 
Are these equivalence relations equivalent? 
Since $\mathcal{P}_C \subset \mathcal{C}$, $P_1 \equiv_1 P_2 \implies P_1 \equiv_2 P_2$. So the question boils down to does $P_1 \equiv_2 P_2 \implies P_1 \equiv_1 P_2$?

for the second equivalence it might be easier to work with $C_L,C_R$ being in a smaller subgroup of $\cal C$. I think the normalizer of $\cal P$ in the unitary group is the generalized permutation group so it might enough to restrict to this subgroup.  A (maby?) quick check would be to count double cosets in each case for small $n=1,2..$ and see if they match.

Does this answer help at all?

@xzkxyz For fixed $n$ all three groups I defined above are finite. This fact can be used to exhaustively check the equivalence relations above for small $n$, but I don't know how to use this fact more generally. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

@unknown You are correct that the normalizer of $\mathcal{P}$ in the unitary group is the generalized permutation group. I'm also interested in the case where $C_R = C_L^\dagger$. Please post an answer if you have insight into this case. The equivalence relations above are equal for $n=1, 2$. In those cases all permutations are in the same equivalence classes by equivalence relation 1 (and therefore by relation 2 as well).

to me it seems likely that the two are the same; I don't have a proof...just some possible directions to look : ${\cal P_C}$ (which has order $|GL(n,2)|*2^n$) covers all the permutations in ${\cal C}$...now to add generalized permutations (aka monomial matrices) you'd have to throw in all pauli $Z$ strings and see if these break the equivalence.

Here is a partial answer based on the suggestion by @unknown.
I'll introduce an intermediate equivalence relation:
Equivalence relation 1.5: $P_1 \equiv_{1.5} P_2$ iff $P_1 = G_L P_2 G_R$ for some $G_L,G_R \in \mathcal{G}_C$.
Here $P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$ as before and $G_L,G_R$ are generalized permutations (or monomial matrices) in the Clifford group. This group is generated by $\mathcal{G}_C = \mathcal{P}_C \cup \mathcal{D}_C$. $\mathcal{D}_C$ is the diagonal Clifford group. $\mathcal{G}_C$ is a strict subgroup of the Clifford group since no Hadamard gates are contained in the group.
As before, since Since $\mathcal{P}_C \subset \mathcal{G}_C \subset \mathcal{C}$, it must be the case that $P_1 \equiv_1 P_2 \implies P_1 \equiv_{1.5} P_2 \implies P_1 \equiv_2 P_2$.
Now, we will look at the conditions for $G_L P_1 G_R \in \mathcal{P}$. This is  a necessary condition for any $P_1 \equiv_{1.5} P_2$.
First, note that any element of $G\in\mathcal{G}_C$ can be written as a product $AD$ where $A\in \mathcal{P}_C$ and $D$ is a diagonal Clifford gate. This is also true for generalized permutations with the full permutation group and any diagonal matrix group.  Then, $$G_L P_1 G_R = A_L D_L P_1 A_R D_R = A_L P_1 (P_1^{-1} D_L P_1) A_R D_R = [A_L P_1 A_R] [A_R^{-1} P_1^{-1} D_L P_1 A_R D_R].$$
Since a diagonal matrix conjugated by a permutation matrix is always a diagonal matrix we see that the terms in the first square bracket are all permutations and therefore the product is a permutation. And since $A_R^{-1} P_1^{-1} D_L P_1 A_R$ is a diagonal matrix, we see that the product of all terms in the second square bracket is a diagonal matrix. For $G_L P_1 G_R$ to be a permutation, the diagonal part must be Identity since this is the only element in the union of diagonal gates and permutations.
So, $A_R^{-1} P_1^{-1} D_L P_1 A_R D_R = I \implies D_R = A_R^{-1} P_1^{-1}D_L^{-1} P_1 A_R$.
Finally, we can substitute this condition into our equivalence relation:  $$G_L P_1 G_R = P_2 \implies A_L D_L P_1 A_R D_R = P_2 \implies A_L D_L P_1 A_R (A_R^{-1} P_1^{-1}D_L^{-1} P_1 A_R) = P_2 \implies A_L P_1 A_R = P_2.$$
This proves that $P_1 \equiv_{1.5} P_2 \implies P_1 \equiv_{1} P_2$.
And from our earlier discussion can see that $P_1 \equiv_1 P_2 \iff P_1 \equiv_{1.5} P_2$.
